# excel date from week number and year

Tags: excel, date

I have the following table in Excel that has year number and week number:

```
Year               Week
-----             ------
2015               33
2014               41
2016               40
```

How can I get a 3rd column that has the date of the corresponding Friday for each row? So, week 33 of 2015 should return: Friday, August 14, 2015.

I have tried to use the date function, weeknum function, but cannot get any consistent results.

Comment: I posted an answer for ISO week numbers which works for your example - if you aren't using ISO week numbers then please advise how your week numbers are defined, when does week 1 start?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `ISO` week numbers then this formula will give the date you want

`=DATE(A2,1,B2*7+2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,3))`

where year is in A2 and week number in B2

Format in required date format

With `ISO` week numbers week 1 always starts on the first Monday on or after 29th December

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the week starts on Sunday and non-ISO week-numbering, the date of the Sunday of Week#1 of any year is given by:

```
=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,1)),DATE(A2,1,1),DATE(A2,1,1)-1,DATE(A2,1,1)-2,DATE(A2,1,1)-3,DATE(A2,1,1)-4,DATE(A2,1,1)-5,DATE(A2,1,1)-6)
```

Then add **5** to move to Friday. Then add:

```
(B2-1)*7
```

to advance to the proper week:

```
=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,1)),DATE(A2,1,1),DATE(A2,1,1)-1,DATE(A2,1,1)-2,DATE(A2,1,1)-3,DATE(A2,1,1)-4,DATE(A2,1,1)-5,DATE(A2,1,1)-6)+5+(B2-1)*7
```

[image]

Comment: My ISO week number suggestion takes the first Monday on or after 29th Dec, as week 1, this is effectively taking first Sunday on or after 26th Dec, as such it can be done with the same approach I used, i.e. `=DATE(A2,1,B2*7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,1))`